# Optimized web image resolution for iPad Pro display

Tags: ios, image, ipad, responsive-design, photoshop

I'm creating a header image (full screen width) for a responsive website.

What's the optimal resolution that will still look good on the 12.9" iPad Pro?

My normal workflow is to create an image at 72 PPI in Photoshop.

The specification shows that it has a resolution of 2732 x 2048 at 226 pixels per inch.

I don't want it to look pixelated when viewing on iPad Pro in landscape mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iPad Pro actually has 2732 x 2048 pixels that it uses to display the screen but we the user sees this rendered as a 1336x1024 display.

So what this means is if you want an image that takes up 100px on the iPad Pro screen you need to use a 200px (2x) image at 72dpi to get that retina sharpness. Alternatively, a 100pt (point) image at 226dpi.

So for a full size image for iPad Pro you would want to output your image at 2732x2048 at 72dpi

People on my team often find it useful to design at 1x but ensure that all raster images in a document are converted to Smart Objects so they can be scaled back up to 2x without quality loss and then output at 72dpi to take advantage of the  (now legacy) Save for Web tools in Photoshop

Comment: Do I need to serve two different versions of the same image?  Or simple serve the highest resolution image to all devices?  If I don't serve the full resolution image per iPad Pro's specs, will it still scale my image without distortion?

Comment: The amount of images you need to serve depends on your usage. As this is web best practice would be to use an img element in your HTML that uses the srcset attribute. This allows you to serve out appropriately sized images to the appropriate devices. Be aware that no one on a mobile wants to download a 2732x2048 image! If you state in your css that you want an img to be 100px X 100px it will display at 100px x 100px. The difference is that if you use a 100px or 1x image it will look fuzzy on the iPad Pro. To be razor sharp it would be a 200px X 200px image in a 100px X 100px image slot.

Comment: For device with 2x support, does `srcset` attribute replace the `src` attribute?  Since I do not own an iPad Pro, Is there a way for me to debug this in Chrome to ensure proper image is being loaded?

Comment: srcset works in combination with src. Browsers that don't support srcset, they will just fallback to using src. Browsers that do support it will look for the declared image that is most relevant to use from the descriptors you add after each image. As for debugging, someone may correct may me but I think you're gonna need access to some kind of retina device. Can't speak for Chrome but Safari developer tools are really useful for debugging on phone/tablet if you don't have access to a retina laptop. I highly recommend using srcset, your users benefit in bandwidth optimisation & image quality!

Comment: You could set the resolution to 300 dpi, that wouldn't change a thing. Pixels are pixels. The browser won't care about dpi until you decide to print the image.