# How to set the dimension and resolution format in the images in iPad pro?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in 12.9 iPad Pro. In this app, I need to set the background images. So I need to know what are the dimensions to set on the background in 12.9 iPad pro phone. How to set the @1x,@2x,@3x and its resolutions?

Comment: check this  may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820476/optimized-web-image-resolution-for-ipad-pro-display

Answer (score 0):

1x will be 1366 x 1024 in portrait 2x will be 2732 x 2048 in portrait

1x will be 1024 x 1366 in landscape 2x will be 2048 x 2732 in landscape

Comment: I NEED IN LANDSCAPE

Comment: i need in @1x,@2x,@3x also

Comment: in landscape 1x will be   1024 X 1366  2x will be 2048 X 2732. check this

Comment: iPad will use only 2x and 3x Images. So set dimension accordingly.

Comment: what about its resolution

Comment: and what about the the @3x

Comment: To deeply understand please follow apple official documentation, https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/

Comment: set the images above 2x and 3x  then check

Answer (score 0):

For 12.9" iPad you need the images to be in the following resolutions.

iPad Pro (12.9 Inch)

@1x

Portrait  **2048 x 2732**

Landscape **2732 x 2048**

@2x multiply the value by 2

@3x multiply the value by 3

**Note***

- Its not necessary to have the image at 2732 x 2048 resolution. You can also have larger images, But if you use this resolution images then it will look fine.
- Also this resolution will be helpful while you deal with "**Launch Image**" for this device. For iPad 12.9 your launch image size should be **2048 x 2732**

Comment: what   about the pixel

Comment: Pixels depends on the clarity of image you need, Its your personal interest. If you want your image to be more clear you need to add higher pixels.

Comment: for giving the button what dimension should give

Comment: You mean you need to assign image(2732 x 2048) for a button ?

Comment: It all depends on the size of the button, For example if your button size is (50 x 50) then your image size @1x can be 50 x 50 (also calculate for @ 2x & @ 3x as said in the answer). Anything lesser will make the image look blurry, anything higher will make image crispy. So use right size of image for each button.